# Create a zip with no root directory with universal sbt-native-packager

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt, sbt-native-packager

I use universal sbt-native-packager to generate a zip file distribution.

```
sbt universal:packageBin
```

The generated zip file, once extracted, contains everything inside a main directory named as my zip file:

```
unzip my-project-0.0.1.zip

my-project-0.0.1/bin
my-project-0.0.1/lib
my-project-0.0.1/conf
...
```

How can I create a zip that has no root folder, so that when extracted it will have a structure like that?

```
bin
lib
conf
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not confident enough with sbt and scala to submit a pull request.
bash scripting has to be excluded right now, so my current (and ugly) solution is this one:

`packageBin in Universal := {
    val originalFileName = (packageBin in Universal).value
    val (base, ext) = originalFileName.baseAndExt
    val newFileName = file(originalFileName.getParent) / (base + "_dist." + ext)
    val extractedFiles = IO.unzip(originalFileName,file(originalFileName.getParent))
    val mappings: Set[(File, String)] = extractedFiles.map( f => (f, f.getAbsolutePath.substring(originalFileName.getParent.size + base.size + 2)))
    val binFiles = mappings.filter{ case (file, path) => path.startsWith("bin/")}
    for (f <- binFiles) f._1.setExecutable(true)
    ZipHelper.zip(mappings,newFileName)
    IO.move(newFileName, originalFileName)
    IO.delete(file(originalFileName.getParent +  "/" + originalFileName.base))
    originalFileName
}`

The solution proposed on github seems to be way nicer than mine even tough it doesn't work for me:
https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager/issues/276

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it looks like the name of that top-level directory is fixed to be the same as the name of the distributable zip (check out line 24 of [the ZipHelper source](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/typesafe/sbt/packager/universal/ZipHelper.scala) on GitHub).

So unless you feel like making it configurable and submitting a pull request, it might just be easier to modify the resulting zip on the command line (assuming some flavour of UNIX):

```
unzip my-project-0.0.1.zip && cd my-project-0.0.1 && zip -r ../new.zip * && cd -
```

This will create `new.zip` alongside the existing zipfile - you could then `mv` it over the top if you like.